# Conditional Formatting Based on Number Range

Tags: xslt, formatting, number

I'm trying to add conditional formatting to a custom list based on whether or not a field contains a number in a certain range (i.e., if the field contains a number less than 15, i'd like the background to be red. It the field contains a number between 15 and 30, I'd like the background to be yellow). After much searching, I think I have the right code for the less than 15 scenario, but no formatting is being applied to the list when I save it. Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong? Here's the code I am using:

```
<Xsl>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" version="1.0" exclude-  result-prefixes="xsl msxsl ddwrt"  xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime"  xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20"  xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas- microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls"  xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft- com:office:office"> 
<xsl:include href="/_layouts/xsl/main.xsl"/> 
<xsl:include href="/_layouts/xsl/internal.xsl"/> 
<xsl:param name="AllRows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[$EntityName = '' or (position() &gt;= $FirstRow and position() &lt;= $LastRow)]"/>
<xsl:param name="dvt_apos">&apos;</xsl:param>
<xsl:template name="FieldRef_body.Days_x0020_On_x0020_Hand" ddwrt:dvt_mode="body" match="FieldRef[@Name='Days_x0020_On_x0020_Hand']" mode="body" ddwrt:ghost="" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal">
<xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
<span>
    \
<xsl:attribute name="style">
        <xsl:if test="number($thisNode/@Days_x0020_On_x0020_Hand) &lt; 15" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" ddwrt:cf_explicit="1">color: #FFFFFF; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; background-color: #CC0000;</xsl:if>
    </xsl:attribute>
    </span></xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="FieldRef_Attachments_header.Attachments" ddwrt:dvt_mode="header" match="FieldRef[(@Type='Attachments') and @Name='Attachments']" mode="header" ddwrt:ghost="" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal">
<th class="ms-vh-icon" nowrap="nowrap" scope="col" onmouseover="OnChildColumn(this)">
  <xsl:call-template name="dvt_headerfield">
    <xsl:with-param name="fieldname">Attachments</xsl:with-param>
    <xsl:with-param name="fieldtitle">&lt;img border=&apos;0&apos; alt=&apos;<xsl:value-of select="'Attachments'"/>&apos; src=&apos;/_layouts/images/attachhd.gif&apos;</xsl:with-param>
    <xsl:with-param name="displayname">Attachments</xsl:with-param>
    <xsl:with-param name="fieldtype">Attachments</xsl:with-param>
  </xsl:call-template>
</th>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:**

in June 2017, Microsoft disabled the use of JavaScript in a Calculated Column

That means given answers may not apply  for newer SharePoint versions

For long explanation and work arounds see:
[June 13th 2017 Microsoft blocked handling HTML markup in SharePoint calculated fields - how to get the same functionality back](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218102/june-13th-2017-microsoft-blocked-handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-f/218110#218110)

---

## Calculated Column (**SP2010** / 2013 / Online)

You can get the same effect without any complex XSLT by creating a Calculated Column **and** setting the output type to Date (*or anything but Single Line Text*) which will execute the HTML, **but only in a View, this does NOT work on Forms**

```
="<DIV style='background:"
&IF([Days On Hand]<15,"lightcoral",IF([Days On Hand]<30,"yellow","white"))
&";color:black;font-weight:bold;text-align:center'>"
&[Days On Hand]
&"</DIV>"
```

- Explanation on How this works (do read the Pros & Cons!): https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/#/How
- All my SO answers applying this technique for Status and Due Date etc:
  https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a32871%20ICC

### Client Side Rendering (CSR - SP2013/Online)

The modern 2013, Online solution solution (which also works in Forms) would be to use Client Side Rendering (CSR) JavaScript

You do not need an extra Calculated Column then to change the look, you override (same as with XSLT) how the field is rendered by SharePoint

See [iCSR](http://icsr.github.io) which makes CSR development a bit easier.

With [iCSR](http://icsr.github.io) loaded in a View or Form, all you need in the CSR file is:

```
iCSR.Me({
  file:'~sitecollection/Style Library/daysonhand.js',
  Fields:{
    Days_x0020_On_x0020_Hand:{
      View:function(ctx){
        var value=ctx.CurrentItem[this.Name];
        var style="text-align:center;color:black;font-weight:bold";
        var color='white';
        if(value<15){
          color='lightcoral';
        } else if(value<30){
          color='yellow'
        }
        return String.format("<DIV style='background:{0};{1}'>{2}</DIV>",color,style,value);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Without the [iCSR](http://icsr.github.io) library you need some 10 more lines of standard SharePoint CSR boilerplate code.

#### Days on Hand is a calculation based on a Date?

I presume DaysOnHand is a Calculated Column based on a `SubmitDate` **Date** field?

The real power of [iCSR](http://icsr.github.io) then is:

```
iCSR.Me({
  file:'~sitecollection/Style Library/daysonhand.js',
  Fields:{
    SubmitDate:iCSR.DueDate({
        ranges: [      15   ,    30        ],
        colors: ['red' , 'yellow' , 'white']
    })
  }
});
```

iCSR does the DaysOnHand (Today calculation) for you.. so you do not need that Column
(*except when you use it for something more (eg. workflow) then just display in SharePoint*)

Comment: Many thanks! The calculated column solution worked perfectly. For some reason, I could not get the XSLT to work

Comment: Be sure to read the Pros & Cons link I referenced.. but it is powerfull.. Here are some cool examples that make you View interactive: http://viewmaster365.com/#/Create/

Answer (score 0):

You want `<xsl:choose>`:

```
<xsl:attribute name="style">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="number($thisNode/@Days_x0020_On_x0020_Hand) &lt; 15">
            color: yellow;
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="number($thisNode/@Days_x0020_On_x0020_Hand) &lt; 30">
            color: red;
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            color: blue;
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:attribute>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. This still does not adjust the list for some reason. I may have an error in my code elsewhere. Thank you anyway; I was able to solve my issue using a calculated column instead.

Answer (score 0):

Or use template rules:

```
<xsl:attribute name="style">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@Days" mode="style"/>
</xsl:attribute>

<xsl:template match="@Days[. &lt; 30]" priority="3">color: red;</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@Days[. &lt; 15]" priority="2">color: yellow;</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@Days" priority="1">color: blue;</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I believe I'm entering the code incorrectly as this still did not change the appearance of the list. There may be an error elsewhere that I am having trouble locating. I was able to solve my issue using a calculated column though.