# add 15 days to date variable

Tags: javascript

I have the following line of code that pulls a list field date  and stores it in a variable called  `dueDate`:

```
var dueDate = new Date(ctx.CurrentItem.ReminderDate);
```

How do I create another variable or set the existing one plus 15 days?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dates are calculated in  milliseconds (*since 1/1/1970*)

with

- 1000 milliseconds in a second
- 60 seconds in a minute
- 60 minutes in an hour
- 24 hours in a day

**Each day is** 1000*60*60*24 = **86400000** milliseconds

to prevent typos and type less characters you can use the scientific notation: **864e5**

So to add 15 days, the JavaScript code is:

```
var dueDate = new Date(ctx.CurrentItem.ReminderDate);
var anotherDate = new Date( dueDate/1 + 864e5*15 );
```

The important part is **dueDate/1** , where a Date value is converted to milliseconds.

Note that this includes the time part of the date notation, 15*24 hours are added.

If you are developing conditional color formatting with CSR,
see: [Conditional Formatting Based on Number Range](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/178358/conditional-formatting-based-on-number-range/178408#178408)

CSR note: the `this` scope in a CSR called function references ctx.CurrentItem

so

```
var dueDate = new Date(ctx.CurrentItem.ReminderDate);
```

**can** be written as:

```
var dueDate = new Date(this.ReminderDate);
```